# contactus php, receiving blank mails

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

Hope this kind of questions are answered lot many times but I have went through most of them and din't found any solution please help to solve my problem.

I had a html form

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" enctype="text/plain"  name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="vname" id="vname" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="vemail" id="vemail" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="vsubject" id="vsubject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="vmessage" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and here is my php code for sending email

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['vname'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['vemail'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['vsubject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['vmessage'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'myemail';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die();
```

Giving data and clicking on submit sending the emails but receiving blank data

Name:

Email:

Subject:

Message:

(unknown sender)

(no subject) - Name: Email: Subject: Message:

please help as I am very new to PHP

I am using CENTOS web panel with Apache

Comment: remove the @ from the `mail` command to see if any error shows up, and check the value of the variables you use by using `echo` or `print_r`

Comment: Its not throwing any error, but i am sure I am getting data of html to my php page. Here is what the change I have done  //$email_from = $email;

Comment: I am not sure what your change was supposed to do. What is the output of `echo $body` when placed after setting the value of `$body`